# How to use report time period in bulk download from bing ads api

Tags: python, bing, bing-ads-api

I am downloading some tables from Bing using the bulk service and want to limit the amount of data according to time. In my download paramters I am using `report_time_period = ['Yesterday']` but keep getting an error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'report_time_period'`

here are my other parameters that seem to be working:

```
download_parameters = DownloadParameters(
data_scope=['EntityData'],
download_entities= ['Keywords'],
report_time_period = ['Yesterday'], #error
file_type=REPORT_FILE_FORMAT,
last_sync_time_in_utc=None,
result_file_directory = FILE_DIRECTORY,
result_file_name = DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME,
overwrite_result_file = True,
timeout_in_milliseconds=3600000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the SUDS factory to create PerformanceStatsDateRange. Here is a link to an [example](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-Python-SDK/blob/master/examples/BingAdsPythonConsoleExamples/BingAdsPythonConsoleExamples/v11/bulk_service_manager_demo.py#L17). I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am now getting this error message: `There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v11:PerformanceStatsDateRange. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Microsoft.AdCenter.Advertiser.CampaignManagement.Api.DataContracts.V11.PerformanceStatsDateRange. The value '' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.'` Do you know what it could be about?